# Change td color on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a table, i want to change color or `<td>` on checkbox checked inside of that `<td>`

```
<table>
 <% for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                   {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <%Response.Write(Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["StartTime"].ToString()).ToString("hh:mm")); %>
                            -
                            <%Response.Write(Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EndTime"].ToString()).ToString("hh:mm")); %></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    } %>
            </table>
```

Comment: change the color of td on Checkbox checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/KPXrU/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>   
 </table>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on("change", function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#cd0000');
        else
            $(this).parent().css('background-color', '');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the  tags in jquery. **Refer below two links**

From these links, understand how to get all  tags in jquery and then you can play around with that .. may be the second link can give you more idea

[Get all the td tags of table which in div tag using JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584450/get-all-the-td-tags-of-table-which-in-div-tag-using-jquery)

[Cannot set the background color of "TD" using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875553/cannot-set-the-background-color-of-td-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('[id^="CheckBox"]').on('change',function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).parent().css('background','red');
   }else{
      $(this).parent().css('background','');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. SHould also work in all IEs:

```
(function($){

    $(function() {
        var _ie = /msie\s[6789]/gi.test(window.navigator.userAgent),
            _event = _ie ? 'propertychange' : 'change';

        $('td').each(function() {
            var el = $(this),
                input = el.find('input');

            input.bind(_event, function() {
                el.css('color', '#yourcolor');
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```